# How to call _IOR macro of C using JNA?

Tags: android, c, usb, jna

I am trying to use

```
#define USBDEVFS_CLAIMINTERFACE    _IOR('U', 15, unsigned int)
```

from usbdevice_fs.h header file in Java Android

How to call _IOR using Java

Comment: You can't "call" macros.

Comment: Assuming `_IOR` comes from `#include <linux/ioctl.h>` you need to work out what magic number the macro produces and use that number to define a constant in your Java code.

Comment: If you want to find out what the actual magic numbers are, write a small C program to print them out.

Comment: I'm pretty sure Android has its own API for claiming USB interfaces. Maybe you should use that.

Comment: Thanks Ian. I'm aware of that but for efficient perspective I would like to use ioctl commands for bulk transfer and others

Answer (score 0):

You can't call c macros. You will need to call local functions other way

Comment: Thanks. I understand i can't call C Macros but how can i call _IOR, _IO, _IORW etc.,

Comment: You need to implement it (those calculations) in your Java program.

Comment: Can you example for Calculating this _IOR('U', 15, unsigned int)?

Comment: Open ioctl.h from the framework/osyou use and see not it is implemented. Then write the appropriate java methods